# How can I fix problems with errors I am getting from NPM install

Tags: angular, npm, command-line-interface, npm-install

I am new to Angular and I am following a course to get better at it. However, I need to install bootstrap for this project I am doing. For this I hit the command:

npm install --save bootstrap@3

I also tried it without save, since I found the default saves it locally for you now anyways, but still does not work. I also figured that none of the 'npm install' commands works for me anymore. I get errors saying: modules not found.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^
```

I have installed the latest NodeJS and Angular version on my machine. Any help would be hihgly appreciated.

Comment: in cmd check:-
node -v  , what do you get?

Comment: I get the following output: v10.15.1

Comment: and with
npm -v ?

Comment: With npm -v I get an error, the output is as follows:

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:58

Comment: can you please extend the question with the path variables you added?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED:

For the ones having this problem, it is due a permission issue. When I ran it as ad admin in the nodeJS CMD, it worked for me. Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED: For the ones having this problem, it is due a permission issue. When I ran it as ad admin in the nodeJS CMD, it worked for me. Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the PATH to `C:\Program Files\nodejs` from `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin` that should help

Comment: It seems my NODE_HOME is allready set to C:\Program Files\nodejs

Comment: So PATH seems good. Try running it in cmd ``SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%`` it may solve your problem. My friend had same situation and running this command fixed it.

Comment: then need to set the node home in path as %NODE_HOME%
is it there?

Comment: Tried it, still does not work. I also tried running it as an admin, but that does not solve anything either. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, I don't have more ideas right now but reinstalling may help. Good luck!